# Expression for getting total value of a field etc

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I need help for the following

1) Could you give me expression for getting total of a field in SSRS

2) My date saved in database is mm/dd/yy, when shown in report, I want to show it like May 21, 2011, How?

Thanks a lot.
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

1) =Sum(Fields!YourField.Value)

2) =Format(Parameters!DateField.Value,"MMM dd,yyyy")

This answer your questions?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Could you also advise for expression two figures after decimal point (e.g 12545.25)? Thanks

Comment: It seems you need to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(VS.95).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(VS.95).aspx